# PC kills network connection in sleep mode and outlook doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, sleep, microsoft-outlook-2016, hybrid-sleep

I'm having an issue where my PC goes to sleep and the network nic dies and doesn't connect to internet. Outlook stops working until the machine gets restarted after waking up from deep sleep mode...

How can I make sure the internet connection doesn't get killed so Outlook keeps flowing and working.

Answer (score 1):

Make a .reg file with the following content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power]
"HiberbootEnabled"=dword:00000000
```

Run it to import it.

Additionally, from your power management settings, uncheck the option to "turn off device to save power" from your network card.

This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Internet does not work when the computer has been suspended or hibernated. Try updating your drivers (BIOS, Network and Power) to see if newer drivers work for you. Otherwise, you need to wake it up (yourself or scheduled task) to re-establish Internet and receive email. I do this myself (modern AC wireless drivers)

If you want to be always connected and email flowing, just leave the machine turned ON.

Comment: Hey John thanks for the response. Sorry if I misled you. However, this occurs after waking the computer up manually, meaning, the connection never comes back live after the PC wakes up

Comment: Perhaps update all of the following:  BIOS, Chipset, Network Driver and Power Manager

Comment: thanks. By update you mean to install the latest firmware...?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would do

Comment: I'll see what results I'll get out of it. I'm personally thinking the process lies in the BIOS somewhere or the network nic adapter settings. I've uncheck the network adapter setting where the machine has power to turn off this device.. but it doesn't help

Comment: @John Newer WiFi chipsets allow for network connection to be maintained while PC is in sleep mode.

Comment: I have a very new Wireless driver here and it still disconnects when suspended. It connects right away upon waking up

Comment: @John, you need to change your answer before it gets deleted as a non answer. Suggest updating the network drivers.

Comment: Done - change as suggested

Comment: @jw0914 it's not a wireless wifi connection. Wired ethernet.

Comment: @Totti I would add that to your question :)  John, not all WiFi cards will have that feature, but newer CPUs with a supported WiFi card can use a S0iX sleep state, similar to cellular devices' network connectivity during sleep, which maintains the network connection.  Microsoft called in "Connected Standby" in Windows 8 and "[Modern Standby](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby)" in Windows 10.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the feedback and will look to added even though I did say it's a PC with a general consensus that PCs are wired in most cases with the exception to a few models and makes